# I have been facing a strange problem with my MACBOOK Pro SSD

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, ssd, recovery

When booting my Macbook Pro, a question mark inside of a folder is displayed.

I try to go to recovery mode (which happens to be online) and I don't see my Machintosh HD in disk utility.

After certain force restarting and shutdown, my mac boots up properly.

PS: If I do an heavy task and then shutdown, this problem reoccurs.

Comment: Does this happen to be a 2012 MBP 13" non-retina with an aftermarket 2.5" SSD?

Answer (score 2):

This definitely sounds like a hardware problem.

You'll want to take the MacBook Pro back to the place you bought it, or contact Apple, to arrange for repairs.

Remember to check your original invoice to see if it might still be under warranty.